# Integrar gráfico Amcharts en Laravel mediante API Rest Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, php7, amcharts

Estoy integrando la librería Amcharts para añadir unos gráficos a mi dashboard. Para la obtención de los datos que necesito, he creado una ruta API:

```
Route::get('/graphcptsr', [DashboardController::class, 'graphCptsr']);
```

En el controlador indicado tengo la función que obtiene los datos. Estos datos dependerán del tipo de usuario conectado.

```
public function graphCptsr() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    
    $graphcpts = [ 
        array('name' => 'En Evaluación', 'value' => DashboardController::countEvaluationComplaints($user)),
        array('name' => 'En Trámite', 'value' => DashboardController::countProcessComplaints($user)),
        array('name' => 'Gestionadas', 'value' => DashboardController::countManagedComplaints($user)),
        array('name' =>'Rechazadas', 'value' => DashboardController::countRejectedComplaints($user))
    ];

    return response()->json($graphcpts, 200);
}
```

Para lanzar la llamada, en la vista tengo la siguiente función según la documentación de Amcharts para cargar datos externos.

```
am5.net.load('http://canal-denuncias.test:81/api/graphcptsr').then(function(result) {
                var data = am5.JSONParser.parse(result.response);
                console.log(result.response);

                xAxis.data.setAll(data);
                series.data.setAll(data);

                series.appear(1000);
                chart.appear(1000, 100);
            }).catch(function(result) {
                console.log("Error loading " + result.xhr.responseURL);
            });
```

Mi problema es que no sé como enviar un parámetro en la url desde la llamada que hago en la vista (**am5.net.load('http://canal-denuncias.test:81/api/graphcptsr').then(function(result)**) para que la función devuelva los datos según el usuario conectado.

¿Alguien puede indicarme cómo puedo enviar un parámetro a través de dicha Url?

Gracias, Un saludo.

Comment: Nadie que me pueda indicar como puedo pasar un parámetro desde la llamada a la API desde javascript?. Esta es la petición que hago y necesito poder pasar un parámetro (am5.net.load('http://canal-denuncias.test:81/api/graphcptsr').then(function(result)). ¿Alguna idea?